# Wordpress: exclude first 4 post from query

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a template with the next query:

```
<?php
                    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('page');
                    } else {
                        $paged = 1;
                    }
                    query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged  ) );
                ?>

                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('/post-types/home-normal'); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Naturally, if i want to exclude the first 4 post ill use `'offset' => 1` buy in this case, if i go to page 2 of the post list, this is not working, and actually, is showing the same post from page 1, and the same in page 3, everytime the same post

My php knowledge is limited, it can be something from this query? or perhaps is something more globl from the template?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else found this old question.
Forget messing around with 'offset' and breaking everything else, use 'post__not_in' instead.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mytheme_modify_posts_list' );
function mytheme_modify_posts_list( $query ) {
//make sure not messing with your admin search
if( !is_admin() ){
  //in main post list
  if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
    //get your IDs
    $skip = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish' ));
    if($skip){
      $skip_ids = wp_list_pluck($skip->posts, 'ID');
      //apply to query
      $query->set('post__not_in', $skip_ids);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use it like this**

```
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$new_query =new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged, 'offset' => 4 ) );

            ?>

            <?php if ( $new_query->have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php while ( $new_query->have_posts()) :  $new_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part('/post-types/home-normal'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`offset` overrides pagination, because when you get down to the query level, it's paginated via `offset` .

You can still use `offset` though, you just have to do some math to multiply your desired `offset` by the current page number (note that this calculation works because posts per page and `offset` are both 4, you may have to use the `posts_per_page` value in your calculation if the two are different):

```
function my_function_for_excluding_posts( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $offset = 4;
        $paged = 0 == $query->get( 'paged' ) ? 1 : $query->get( 'paged' );
        $query->set( 'offset', $paged * $offset );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_function_for_excluding_posts' );
```

EDIT- filtering `found_posts` so number of pages is correct.

```
function myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination($found_posts, $query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return $found_posts - 5;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
add_filter('found_posts', 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );
```

for more info you can refer this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167179/trying-to-exclude-first-5-posts-from-the-first-page-on-the-homepage)