# Fetch the 3 latest post ids on category/tag pages and exclude them from the main query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to fetch the 3 recent posts on a category or tag page, get their ids and pass them to `$query->set()` to modify the main query.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sands_offset_archive_posts');
function sands_offset_archive_posts($query) {
    global $wp_query;
    // I need to limit the IDs to the first 3 only
    $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query->posts, 'ID' );
    
    //var_dump($post_ids);

    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive()) {
        // pass $post_ids to set() is not working
        $query->set('post__not_in', $post_ids);
    } 
}
```

For some reason `$post_ids` is returning empty when it reaches `$query->set()`

if I replace it with hard-coded ids `266, 272, 274` it works.

`var_dump($post_ids)` returns the following

```
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=5)
  0 => int 266
  1 => int 272
  2 => int 274
  3 => int 278
  4 => int 280
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=5)
  0 => int 266
  1 => int 272
  2 => int 274
  3 => int 278
  4 => int 280
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=5)
  0 => int 266
  1 => int 272
  2 => int 274
  3 => int 278
  4 => int 280
C:\wamp64\www\sands\wp-content\themes\sands-child\functions.php:182:
array (size=5)
  0 => int 266
  1 => int 272
  2 => int 274
  3 => int 278
  4 => int 280
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by creating an additional custom query inside the action `pre_get_posts` and then plucking the ids from it.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sands_offset_archive_posts');
function sands_offset_archive_posts($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && !is_author()) {
        if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive()) {
            $cat_obj = $query->get_queried_object();
            $skip = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'post', 'cat' => $cat_obj->term_id, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => 'desc'));
            if ($skip) {
                $skip_ids = wp_list_pluck($skip->posts, 'ID');
                $query->set('post__not_in', $skip_ids);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Found the answer here: [Wordpress: exclude first 4 post from query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636667/wordpress-exclude-first-4-post-from-query)